# Python POST запрос c данными на кирилице

Tags: python, json, requests, post, http-status-code-400

Отправляю запрос

```
url = '*****'
print(firstname)
print(lastname)
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(accessToken)}
data = {
    "username": str(users),
    "email": email,
    "firstName": firstname,
    "lastName": lastname,
    "enabled": enable,
    "credentials": [
        {
             "type": type,
             "temporary": temporary,
             "value": password
        }
        ],
    "attributes": {
         "mobile": str(mobile)
    }
}
print(data)
response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 409:
    print("Пользователь", users, "уже существует. Продолжаем работать")
    return response.status_code
if response.status_code == 401:
    print("Нужно получить новый токен")
if response.status_code != 201:
    print(response.request.body)
    print(response.status_code)
```

На запрос отдает 400 ошибку (запрос к серверу содержит синтаксическую ошибку)
Вывожу request.body

print(firstname) - ИВАНОВ

print(lastname) - ИВАН

```
print(data)

{'username': '9106005822845', 'email': 'ivan@mail.ru', 'firstName': 'ИВАН', 'lastName': 'ИВАНОВ', 'enabled': 'true', 'credentials': [{'tupe': 'password', 'temporary': 'false', 'value': 'Test1234'}], 'attributes': {'mobile': '9234562341'}}

print(response.request.body)
b'{"username": "9106005822845", "email": "ivan@mail.ru", "firstName": "\\u041d\\u0410\\u0422\\u0410\\u041b\\u042c\\u042f", "lastName": "\\u041c\\u0418\\u0421\\u0410\\u041d ", "enabled": "true", "credentials": [{"tupe": "password", "temporary": "false", "value": "Test1234"}], "attributes": {"mobile": "9234562341"}}'
```

print(response.status_code) - 400

Как отправить запрос с параметрами на кирилице?

Comment: Проверьте запрос в POSTMAN, чтобы убедиться, что проблема с кириллицей в Python, а не с самим запросом.

Comment: `"tupe": type` - одно из них (а именно, первое) явно содержит опечатку

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку с Postman, выполнил запрос в нем и скопировал Python - Requests, изменил data = json.dumps({ *** }) и `data=data`  в  response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers) и все получилось.